# How to use svn list svn+ssh://user@host/home/svn/myrepo without SVN_SSH path.

Tags: svn

1. First, export the `SVN_SSH` env variable:

   ```
   $ export SVN_SSH="ssh -l user -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa"
   ```
2. Second, execute the command below and co is successful:

   ```
   svn co svn+ssh://user@host/home/svn/myrepo
   ```

Now the question:

Is it possible to execute the `svn co svn+ssh://` in a single command? I want to execute the same command in a Windows PC environment.

Answer (score 4):

It is better to store the command `ssh -l user -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa` in the file `~/.subversion/config` in [tunnels] section:

```
[tunnels]

ssh = ssh -l user -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and then do `svn co` in single command. 
Works both Linux and Windows. The config you could find in the directory  `C:\Users\user\Application Data\Subversion`.

Comment: The location on Windows is `%APPDATA%\Subversion\config`, which is only sometimes equivalent to `C:\Users\user\Application Data\Subversion\config`

Answer (score 0):

Read [Tunneling over SSH](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshauth) topic in the SVN book in order to exclude export operation, options for [tunnels] section